# Trying to parse the names (and phD degrees) from a faculty university site. Having trouble getting only that

Tags: python, parsing, web

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #imports beautifulSoup package
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.marshall.usc.edu/faculty/phd' #sets url to a variable
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml") #sets the contents of the page to the variable soup

#names = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'odd views-row-first'})

names = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'views-field views-field-field-faculty-name-last-value active'}) #sets the name 'cell' and tags
#namesU = names.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","")

#names.strip('<td class="views-field views-field-field-faculty-name-last-value active">') 
#names2 = names.sub('<td class="views-field views-field-field-faculty-name-last-value active">', '')

print(names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this problem by using the "text" attribute after your find_all for 'td'.

So, the result you get from find_all, you simply iterate over and get the "text" portion of each part you have and place that in your array of names.

Here is a list comprehension approach to achieve this:

```
names = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'views-field views-field-field-faculty-name-last-value active'})]
```

After running this, the output yields:

```
['Amato, Andrea', 'Banerjee, Trambak', 'Basu, Pallavi', 'Chang, Wayne', 'Chung, Sung Hun', 'Comings, Alison', 'Cui, Hailong', 'DeGroot, Tyler', 'Dutton, Chaumanix', 'Fu, Luella', 'Golrezaei, Negin', 'Grandy, Jake', 'Han, Rong Qing', 'Han, Ju Rie (Alyssa)', 'Harmon, Derek', 'Hong, Jihoon', 'Jia, He', 'Joshi, Priyanka', 'Kays, Allison', 'Kfir, Alon', 'Kim, Jeunghyun', 'Kim, Pureum', 'Kim, Yookyoung', 'Kim , Jennifer', 'Krikorian, Mariam', 'Lang, Tina', 'Lee, Jennifer', 'Lee, Suk won', 'Lee, Yoonju', 'Li, Guang', 'Li, Yuan', 'Ling, Yun', 'Magkotsios, Georgios', 'Min, Bora', 'Newman, David', 'Oh, Seung Hwan', 'Ozkan, Erhun', 'Paulson, Courtney', 'Pei, Lei', 'Pyun, Sung June', 'Raj, Medha', 'Raveendhran, Roshni', 'Rich, Beverly', 'Ritter, Stacey', 'Sahoo, Satish', 'Skripnik, Roman', 'Smallets, Stephanie', 'Song, Shiwon', 'Stamenov, Ventsislav', 'Subler, Megan', 'Talijan, Vuk', 'Uhalde, Arianna', 'Valsesia, Francesca', 'Wan, Yuan', 'Wang, Jue', 'Wang, Weinan', 'Wang, Xuan', 'Wang, Yongzhi (Alex)', 'Wang, Yingfei (Fiona)', 'Wong, Vivian', 'Xia, Jingjing', 'Xing, Zhe (Adele)', 'Xu, Zibin', 'Yang, Louis', 'Yao, Yao', 'Yi, Irene', 'Yordanov, Kristian', 'Yu, Xiaoqian', 'Zhang, Heng', 'Zhang, Yanwei (Wayne)', 'Zhang, Yingguang', 'Zhang, Mengxia']
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with all of this! Although I keep getting the character 'u' right before the first quotation of each array cell like [u'Amato, Andrea', u'Banerjee, Trambak' ....] Any ideas?

Comment: That just means the string is in unicode. This should not be a problem.

Comment: If you really don't want the unicode, you can simply just make sure to convert it to str() inside the list comprehension: `str(i.text.strip())`. If you find this answer acceptable, please upvote and accept.